# Como mostrar os segundos rodando na função date

Tags: php, jquery

Bom dia pessoal, como eu faço para mostrar os segundos rodando na função abaixo? pode ser alguma função em jQuery para animar o php.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/sao_paulo');
//CRIA UMA VARIAVEL E ARMAZENA A HORA ATUAL DO FUSO-HORÀRIO DEFINIDO (BRASÍLIA)
$Asuncion = date('H:i:s', time());
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer via jquery pegando a hora do cliente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>

    <script>
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

    function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
    }

    function myStopFunction() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval

Ou usar o setInterval para chamar uma função que realize a requisição ajax para pegar a hora do servidor em PHP.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Roberto pela contribuição mas nesse caso aí o sistema pega a hora do servidor ou do cliente? e como eu faço para alterar o fuso? exemplo: pegar a hora de NY?

Comment: Neste caso pega a hora do cliente. Para pegar a hora de outro local acredito que teria que retornar o getTime da hora atual e fazer uma soma ou subtração dependendo de qual local precisa. Normalmente usam o momentjs para trabalhar com data